# Python Truncate number is rounding in some cases

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, truncate

I have a pandas dataframe, with columns [QuantityReq] as Float and [Test] as Float. I am trying to get 3 digits after the decimal points. The [Test] column which I create is truncating for 3 digits after decimal, but in some cases it is rounding at the 3rd digit. I have highlighted the error in row 2 and 3 of [Test] column where it is showing 0.869 instead of 0.87 and 59.306 instead of 59.307

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
df['Test'] =  np.trunc( df['QuantityReq']* 1000)/1000
```

Comment: Search for the question "Is floating point broken".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: You might be able to use `np.nextafter` to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `decimal` module it's preferred to deal with float number in python as float numbers have some problems that mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

sample example

```py
from decimal import Decimal

for i in [59.307000, 0.8700000]:
    print(Decimal(i).quantize(Decimal("1.000")))
```

output

```
59.307
0.870
```

for more check [this](https://linuxhint.com/decimal-module-python/).